# Is there a way to figure out which action/filter invoked a function?

Tags: plugins, filters, actions

I'd like a lightweight way to figure out what is invoking a certain action in an effort to provide logic for certain scenarios where I can't help to avoid a function invocation (for example, a new comment firing `edit_post`). Is there a way to figure out which action/filter invoked a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use `current_filter()`.

Comment: That tells me the current action/filter, which is the only information I know of. I'm trying to figure out where that action was invoked. For example, `edit_post` is called in both `wp-includes/comment.php` and `wp-includes/post.php` and I'd like to be able to tell the difference.

Comment: In that case, you have to dig through the stacktrace returned by debug_backtrace(). Or hook your callback from a second callback that itself is hooked into an earlier action that's specific to `wp-includes/comment.php` or `wp-includes/post.php`.

Comment: Or you could use `did_action()`, passing an action that only fires on `wp-includes/comment.php`, for example.